# .write can not be set as a variable without it being executed immediately

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new and as my first 1-week project I decided I would be able to create a random website not so good, but never the less a random website. So here I am stuck at the very beginning because apparently, I can not assign `.write("something")` as a variable without it being executed instantly any help is welcome.

I tried removing .write and using it like this

```
a = "some HTML code"
b = "more HTML code"
choice = [a,b]
randomchoice = random.choice(choice)
f.write(randomchoice)
```

but this just writes a or b in the program

the problem:

```
f.write("""<head>
""")

choices = [ "a", "b" ]

a = f.write("</head>")
b = f.write("<title> A random program </title>")

randomchoice = random.choice(choices)

while randomchoice != "a":
    randomchoice
```

The output should be either `</head>` or `<title> A random program  </title>` and then `</head>`, but the output is both at the same time
edit: f is the file open name.

Comment: Welcome Samoshi. You may need to make this question a bit clearer before we can answer it - it's a bit hard to follow.

Comment: We can't see where `f` comes from in your question, but assuming that it's an open file object,`f.write(whatever)` is calling a method, and will write the supplied value to the file.

Comment: Your first snippet works pretty much perfectly as written. Why not write the second one the same way?

Comment: Because it outputs `a` or `b` when I want it to output what `a` or `b` stand for.

Comment: That's not what happens when I run your code as written in the question. Your first snippet writes either `some HTML code` or `more HTML code`. Note that `[a, b]` means something very different from `["a", "b"]`.

Comment: Yeah... fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as mentioned `f.write` is executed right away and only returns the number of characters written to the file. I believe this will be more in the direction of what you want. Your first snippet was close to this.

```
f.write("""<head>
""")

a = "</head>"
b = "<title> A random program </title>"
choices = [a, b]  # actually use the variables as choices, not strings refering to those variables.

randomchoice = random.choice(choices)

while randomchoice != a:  # again use the variable to check, not the string.
    f.write(randomchoice)
    randomchoice = random.choice(choices)  # get the next random choice
```

Do note that this setup will never actually write `</head>` to the file since we're only writing to the file if it's *not* that value. But this is as far as I can get with your question for now.

Comment: Thank you so much, I know it is a bit late, but this helped me a lot and actually fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The line `a = f.write("</head>")` does not do what you think it does. Any Python expression will **execute** what's on the right side of the assignment (which in this case *will* write to the output), then store the *result* in the variable.

This also means that once you set `randomchoice` to a random value, it will remain set to that value forever and your loop will never end. Think about this and start on your program again.

Comment: Thanks, but I found the problem and fixed it.

Comment: Sure, you could call it that.